# Messaging a __weak object?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

What happens if I send a message to a weak object? Does sending the message possess the object and hold it in memory until return?

I'm thinking of this pattern:

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [weakSelf doSomeAction];
});
```

Assuming `weakSelf` is non-nil when the message is sent, might it be deallocated while `doSomeAction` is working or is it guaranteed to remain valid until `doSomeAction` returns?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [Clang ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics):

> ***Reading*** occurs when performing a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an object lvalue.
>
> - For `__weak` objects, the current pointee is retained and then released at the end of the current full-expression. This must execute atomically with respect to assignments and to the final release of the pointee.

Messaging a weak reference performs an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the variable, which means the value of the weak reference will be retained and then released at the end of the current full-expression (basically, the statement). It's basically equivalent to assigning to a strong variable whose scope only lasts for the current statement, and then messaging that strong variable.

The takeaway here is if you want to message a weak variable once, and never touch it again, and you don't care about the side-effects of evaluating the arguments to the method in the case where the weak reference ends up `nil`, then go ahead and message the weak reference directly. But if you need to refer to the weak reference twice (in separate statements), or the side-effects of evaluating the arguments do matter, then you should assign to a strong variable and test for non-`nil` before proceeding.

Comment: That seems like an implementation quirk to me; I doubt it's documented/guaranteed anywhere. :)

Comment: @Rob: That's almost certainly an implementation quirk as Steven said. The compiler likely used `objc_loadWeak()`, which autoreleases the value, instead of `objc_loadWeakRetained()`, which doesn't. You can't rely on this behavior, as it may change with optimization levels or future versions of the compiler.

Comment: A follow-up question: what potential problems is it then that Apple supplies the "Sending messages to __weak pointers" warning in LLVM 5.0 for? I note that "Repeatedly using a __weak reference" is a separate warning. Unless there's an optimisation where `nil` checking occurs before arguments are evaluated (ie, it doesn't just happen in `objc_msgSend`)?

Comment: @Tommy: While messaging a nil reference a single time, in a scenario where messaging nil is ok, is perfectly benign, the compiler doesn't know that you think it's ok if the reference ends up being nil. It's warning you because, in the general case, using a weak reference in anything other than assigning it to a strong reference is incorrect.

Comment: Good answer but there is one more reason why you might want to assign a weak reference to a strong one prior to messaging it and that is performance. If you message the same weak reference 1000 times in a loop, this will cause 1000 retains and 1000 releases but if you assign it to a strong reference before the loop, there is one retain and one release when then strong var goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

You asked:

> Assuming `weakSelf` is non-`nil` when the message is sent, might it be deallocated while `doSomeAction` is working or is it guaranteed to remain valid until `doSomeAction` returns?

This ARC behavior has changed over time. But nowadays, `weak` references can be released as soon as the last strong reference is removed.

Thus, consider the following:

```objectivec
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)startBackgroundOperation {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [weakSelf doSomeAction];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];
        [weakSelf doSomeAction2];
    });
}

- (void)doSomeAction {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)doSomeAction2 {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

If you have some code invoke `startBackgroundOperation` and let the object be deallocated in the intervening time between `doSomeAction` and `doSomeAction2`, you will see the former will be called and the latter will not. I.e. if there were no more strong references, the object could be deallocated in the middle of the block.

So, if you want weak reference, but want an “all or none” sort of behavior whereby it to be retained for the duration of the closure, we perform what is jokingly referred to as the “`weakSelf`-`strongSelf` dance”:

```objectivec
- (void)startBackgroundOperation {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;        // establish just-in-time strong reference (if `weakSelf` is not yet `nil`)

        [strongSelf doSomeAction];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];
        [strongSelf doSomeAction2];
    });
}
```

This will ensure that the block has a `weak` reference, but if it is not deallocated by the time it hits the assignment of `strongSelf`, then it will establish and maintain a strong reference for the duration of the block.

---

For what it is worth, this `weakSelf`-`strongSelf` pattern is essential when dereferencing ivars with `->` (avoiding race conditions with `weakSelf`).

E.g.

```objectivec
- (void)badDeferenceExample {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if (!weakSelf) { return; }

        NSInteger value = weakSelf->_someIVar;     // this is race and can crash!!!

        ...
    });
}

- (void)properDeferenceExample {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;        // establish just-in-time strong reference (if `weakSelf` is not yet `nil`)

        if (!strongSelf) { return; }

        NSInteger value = strongSelf->_someIVar;   // this is safe

        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you prove this? The evidence so far says you're wrong, that sending a message to a weak object holds a reference to it for the duration of the message.

Comment: @Rob: You're relying on observed behavior, presumably at a particular optimization level (or lack thereof). This is not guaranteed behavior. The compiler is free to nil out `weakSelf` in between the two accesses of it. In your case it's probably using `objc_loadWeak()`, which autoreleases the object (and therefore keeps it alive), but it's not guaranteed to do that in the future or at higher optimization levels.

Comment: @Rob: A full-expression is an expression that is not a sub-expression of another one. You can basically treat it the same as "the statement".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that a strong reference is required for `->`! Avoiding a C pointer-style dereference of an Objective-C object is the reason I'm sending a message instead. I find accessing instance variables through `->` to be an ugly style, even if it is legitimate (as it probably is in this case).

Comment: I have updated the above answer to reflect contemporary ARC behaviors.